# Android Studio: Plugin with id 'android-library' not found

Tags: gradle, android-studio, android-build, build.gradle, gradlew

I've been trying to get ActionBarSherlock to work and having some issue.  One issue I've come across is the following message when trying to build it:

```bsh
Plugin with id 'android-library' not found
```

Specifically:

```bsh
D:\Projects\Android\actionbarsherlock>D:\Projects\Android\gradlew --info build
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using empty settings script.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file 
  'D:\Projects\Android\actionbarsherlock\build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'actionbarsherlock']
Evaluating root project 'actionbarsherlock' using build file 
  'D:\Projects\Android\actionbarsherlock\build.gradle'.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\Projects\Android\actionbarsherlock\build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'actionbarsherlock'.
> Plugin with id 'android-library' not found.
```

I'm treating this as an ABS issue in a seperate thread, so here I'm curious how to address the general issue of:

```bsh
Plugin with id 'android-library' not found
```

Here is the build.gradle:

```groovy
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 14
  buildToolsVersion '17.0.0'

  sourceSets {
    main {
      manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
      java.srcDirs = ['src']
      res.srcDirs = ['res']
    }
  }
}
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 287, accepted):

Instruct Gradle to download Android plugin from Maven Central repository.

You do it by pasting the following code at the beginning of the Gradle build file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.1'
    }
}
```

Replace version string `1.0.+` with the latest version. Released versions of Gradle plugin can be found in [official Maven Repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg:%22com.android.tools.build%22%20AND%20a:%22gradle%22) or on [MVNRepository artifact search](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle).

Comment: For more up-to-date info, a higher version number for com.android.tools is definitely recommended, as also mentioned by @Elenasys in a later answer. Otherwise you can run into this problem: 
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-thinks-2-10-is-less-than-2-2-when-resolving-plugins/13434

Comment: I needed to add this to my *project's* build.gradle, adding it to one module gradle file didn't help

Comment: How will i know which gradel version i have downloaded to? Btw 1.1.1 works for me

Comment: @binil This is a version of Android Gradle plugin not the Gradle itself. All versions are listed on Maven Repository http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle To list build dependencies run `gradle buildEnvironment`

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48451418/2186220, in this thread itself worked for me as of August, 2019.

Comment: this didn't work for me on android studio 4.2 C15 SDK30

Answer (score 30):

Just for the record (took me quite a while) before Grzegorzs answer worked for me I had to install "**android support repository**" through the SDK Manager!

Install it and add the following code above apply plugin: 'android-library' in the build.gradle of actionbarsherlock folder!

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.+'
    }
}
```

Comment: @beworker i already installed "android support repository" but still same issue: "Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'android' not found"

Comment: this didn't work for me on android studio 4.2 C15 SDK30

Answer (score 18):

Use

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

to convert an app module to a library module.  More info here: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html

Comment: changing from com.android-library to com.android.library saved the day here

Answer (score 12):

In later versions, the plugin has changed name to:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

And as already mentioned by some of the other answers, you need the gradle tools in order to use it. Using 3.0.1, you have to use the google repo, not mavenCentral or jcenter:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
        //In IntelliJ or older versions of Android Studio
        //maven {
        //   url 'https://maven.google.com'
        //}
        google()//in newer versions of Android Studio
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
```

Comment: this didn't work for me on android studio 4.2 C15 SDK30

Comment: @MiguelSilva it should still work: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#Convert - what's the error you're getting?

Comment: Hi Zoe. check the answer on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66483502/13794189

Answer (score 7):

Use **`mavenCentral()`** adding in the `build.gradle` file the script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to previous answers, when using Gradle Kotlin DSL, you should add [resolution strategy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#sec:plugins_resolution_strategy) for Android plugins in your `settings.gradle.kts`:

```
pluginManagement {

    repositories {
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }

    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if(requested.id.namespace == "com.android") {
                useModule("com.android.tools.build:gradle:${requested.version}")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Then, you need to specify plugin version in your `build.gradle.kts`, e.g.:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library") version "4.1.3"
}
```

No `buildscript` is required.

Answer (score 3):

For me, on android studio 4.2 C15 SDK30, this is what worked:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven {
            url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.lint/lint-gradle-api'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0-beta05"
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the below to the `build.gradle` project module:

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when I was applying plugin like this in `build.gradle`:

```
plugin {
     id 'com.android.library'
     id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}
```

This plugin won't work automatically and you have to add following code in your `settings.gradle` file.

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}
```

Even after this it would throw the error of not able to find argument android() which is because of the fact that plugins are not applied automatically so I changed this in `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply true
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply true
}
```

Including `apply true` at the end worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Believe it or not, an empty `settings.gradle` file in the `com.android.library` module's root directory brought this error back from the grave in Android Studio 4.2.2.

Deleting the empty `settings.gradle` file fixed it.