# Imported Android Studio Project no Build.gradle or settings.gradle file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have imported an Android Studio project into Android Studio yet the error appears:

```
Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'android' not found.
```

It appears on import that the Build.gradle file for the project and the settings.gradle file were not created:

[image]

as it should be given my other app:

[image]

There is not a tutorial or source for creating these files, how can I these files be generated to allow the app to run?

Comment: Did you try clicking going to the `Build` button and clicking `Clean` and `Rebuild`?

Comment: I tried that, but the same error prevented it from building: The error appeared: Error:(1) A problem occurred evaluating root project 'app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'android']
   > Plugin with id 'android' not found.

Comment: Have you tried looking at this [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153739/android-studio-plugin-with-id-android-library-not-found) post?

Comment: @Freddie_V4 there is no Build.gradle file to allow for this to paste into. From my original question, I need to get the Build.gradle project file into the app

Comment: Post your build.gradle files

Comment: I am having same issue does anybody solve this then please do comment the solution..

Comment: @Sauron Got anything ??