# Android module build error : Plugin with id 'org.android.library' not found

Tags: android, module, build.gradle

In `Android Studio 2.3.3`, I created a project and created new module (`HTTP`) of type `Android Library`. And added a java file to that module package.

While building, I am getting error like `Plugin with id 'org.android.library' not found` from the build.grade of that module (`HTTP/build.gradle`). First line of that build.gradle is having

`apply plugin: 'org.android.library'`

No error from `app/build.gradle` file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153739/android-studio-plugin-with-id-android-library-not-found

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio: Plugin with id 'android-library' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153739/android-studio-plugin-with-id-android-library-not-found)

Comment: developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html - It talks about converting app module to library module. Changing from com.android.application to com.android.library. But my problem was different, I created an android library but in that org.android.library was there by default. Which caused problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved after changing

`apply plugin: 'org.android.library'`

to

`apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html - It talks about converting app module to library module. Changing from `com.android.application` to `com.android.library`. But my problem was I created an android library but in that `org.android.library` was there by default. Which caused problem.