# Gradle error Plugin with id 'com.android.model.library' not found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project and i'm trying to use the plugin

> com.android.model.library

instead of

> com.android.library

But when i change this, i have this error:

[image]

What can i do to enable this plugin?

Comment: Have you tried this solution ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18153928/4698320

Comment: Yes, it's not working in my case :(

Comment: have you added `classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0-alpha4"` or something similar to your root build.gradle?

Comment: ok, newer version is: `classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.11.1"`

Comment: Do an `Unable to load class 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.model.ModelBuilder'.`